# What is the best way to load a multi-dimensional XML document using Linq to XML while maintaining parent/child relationships?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a multi-dimensional xml document to maintain my navigation elements:

```html
  <level1 title="Personal Banking" controller="PersonalBanking" description="Personal Banking"  mainNavOrder="1"  >
    <level2 title="Personal Deposits" controller="PersonalBanking" action="PersonalDeposits" mainNavOrder="10"  >
      <level3 title="Checking Accounts" controller="PersonalBanking" action="PersonalDeposits" page="CheckingAccounts"   />
      <level3 title="Savings Accounts" controller="PersonalBanking" action="PersonalDeposits" page="SavingsAccounts"   />
      <level3 title="Certificates Of Deposit" controller="PersonalBanking" action="PersonalDeposits" page="CertificatesOfDeposit"   />
    </level2>
    <level2 title="Compare Current Rates" controller="PersonalBanking" action="Rates" mainNavOrder="20"  >
      <level3 title="Checking Rates" controller="PersonalBanking" action="Rates" page="CheckingAccounts"   />
    </level2>
    <level2 title="Consumer Lending" controller="PersonalBanking" action="ConsumerLending" mainNavOrder="30"  >
      <level3 title="Auto Loans" controller="PersonalBanking" action="ConsumerLending" page="AutoLoans"   />
      <level3 title="Recreational Loans" controller="PersonalBanking" action="ConsumerLending" page="RecreationalLoans"   />
      <level3 title="Home Equity Loans" controller="PersonalBanking" action="ConsumerLending" page="HomeEquityLoans"   />
      <level3 title="Other Loans" controller="PersonalBanking" action="ConsumerLending" page="OtherLoans"   />
    </level2>
    <level2 title="Personal Services" controller="PersonalBanking" action="PersonalServices"  mainNavOrder="40" >
      <level3 title="ATM &amp; Debit Cards" controller="PersonalBanking" action="PersonalServices" page="ATMDebitCards"   />
      <level3 title="Online Banking &amp; Bill Payment" controller="PersonalBanking" action="PersonalServices" page="OnlineBankingBillPayment"   />
      <level3 title="Overdraft Protection" controller="PersonalBanking" action="PersonalServices" page="OverdraftProtection"   />
    </level2>
    <level2 title="Education Center" controller="EducationCenter" mainNavOrder="50"  />

  </level1>
```

The previous XML example is just a portion of the nodes. I am loading it in using Linq to XML. This just seems to be a very ugly way to do it. I would like to refactor this, but don't really know how.

```
var pages = sitemapData.Descendants("level1")
                        .Select(p1 => new SitemapNode
                        {
                            Title = (string)p1.Attribute("title"),
                            Action = (string)p1.Attribute("action") ?? "Index",
                            Controller = (string)p1.Attribute("controller"),
                            Page = (string)p1.Attribute("page") ?? "",
                            Description = (string)p1.Attribute("description") ?? "",
                            Blank = bool.Parse((string)p1.Attribute("blank") ?? "false"),
                            Level = p1.Ancestors().Count(),
                            mainNavOrder = (int?)p1.Attribute("mainNavOrder") ?? 0,
                            sections = p1.Elements("alternativeSection")
                                    .Select(n => (string)n.Attribute("name")),
                            subNodes = p1.Elements("level2")
                                .Select(p2 => new SitemapNode
                                {
                                    Title = (string)p2.Attribute("title"),
                                    Action = (string)p2.Attribute("action") ?? "Index",
                                    Controller = (string)p2.Attribute("controller"),
                                    Page = (string)p2.Attribute("page") ?? "",
                                    Description = (string)p2.Attribute("description") ?? "",
                                    Blank = bool.Parse((string)p2.Attribute("blank") ?? "false"),
                                    Level = p2.Ancestors().Count(),
                                    mainNavOrder = (int?)p2.Attribute("mainNavOrder") ?? 0,
                                    sections = p2.Elements("alternativeSection")
                                                    .Select(n => (string)n.Attribute("name")),
                                    subNodes = p2.Elements("level3")
                                    .Select(p3 => new SitemapNode
                                    {
                                        Title = (string)p3.Attribute("title"),
                                        Action = (string)p3.Attribute("action") ?? "Index",
                                        Controller = (string)p3.Attribute("controller"),
                                        Page = (string)p3.Attribute("page") ?? "",
                                        Description = (string)p3.Attribute("description") ?? "",
                                        Blank = bool.Parse((string)p3.Attribute("blank") ?? "false"),
                                        Level = p3.Ancestors().Count(),
                                        mainNavOrder = (int?)p3.Attribute("mainNavOrder") ?? 0,
                                        sections = p3.Elements("alternativeSection")
                                                    .Select(n => (string)n.Attribute("name"))
                                    })

                                    .OrderBy(n => n.Title)
                                }

                                )
                                .OrderBy(n => n.Title)
                        }); 
            Sitemap.AddRange(pages.ToList<SitemapNode>());
```

Is there a better way to load these while still maintaining the child/parent relationship? Is this something I should even worry about since it works?

Comment: Good lord man, why don't you just use the deserializer offered by the framework?

Comment: Yeah, I know it wasn't even near perfect, that's why I asked. Thanks for the advice, I definitely think the deserializer is a way to go, I'm just not too familiar with it, so I will look into it in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
            "<Root>" +
            "<level1 title=\"Personal Banking\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" description=\"Personal Banking\"  mainNavOrder=\"1\">" +
                "<level2 title=\"Personal Deposits\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"PersonalDeposits\" mainNavOrder=\"10\">" +
                  "<level3 title=\"Checking Accounts\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"PersonalDeposits\" page=\"CheckingAccounts\"/>" +
                  "<level3 title=\"Savings Accounts\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"PersonalDeposits\" page=\"SavingsAccounts\"/>" +
                  "<level3 title=\"Certificates Of Deposit\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"PersonalDeposits\" page=\"CertificatesOfDeposit\"/>" +
                "</level2>" +
                "<level2 title=\"Compare Current Rates\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"Rates\" mainNavOrder=\"20\">" +
                  "<level3 title=\"Checking Rates\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"Rates\" page=\"CheckingAccounts\"/>" +
                "</level2>" +
                "<level2 title=\"Consumer Lending\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"ConsumerLending\" mainNavOrder=\"30\">" +
                  "<level3 title=\"Auto Loans\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"ConsumerLending\" page=\"AutoLoans\"/>" +
                  "<level3 title=\"Recreational Loans\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"ConsumerLending\" page=\"RecreationalLoans\"/>" +
                  "<level3 title=\"Home Equity Loans\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"ConsumerLending\" page=\"HomeEquityLoans\"/>" +
                  "<level3 title=\"Other Loans\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"ConsumerLending\" page=\"OtherLoans\"/>" +
                "</level2>" +
                "<level2 title=\"Personal Services\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"PersonalServices\"  mainNavOrder=\"40\">" +
                  "<level3 title=\"ATM &amp; Debit Cards\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"PersonalServices\" page=\"ATMDebitCards\"/>" +
                  "<level3 title=\"Online Banking &amp; Bill Payment\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"PersonalServices\" page=\"OnlineBankingBillPayment\"/>" +
                  "<level3 title=\"Overdraft Protection\" controller=\"PersonalBanking\" action=\"PersonalServices\" page=\"OverdraftProtection\"/>" +
                "</level2>" +
                "<level2 title=\"Education Center\" controller=\"EducationCenter\" mainNavOrder=\"50\"/>" +
              "</level1>" +
              "</Root>";


            XElement sitemapData = XElement.Parse(xml);

            var pages = sitemapData.Descendants("level1")
                        .Select(p1 => SitemapNode.GetNode(p1,1) 
            );
            List<SitemapNode> Sitemap = new List<SitemapNode>();
            Sitemap.AddRange(pages.ToList<SitemapNode>());

        }


        public class SitemapNode
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Action { get; set; }
            public string Controller { get; set; }
            public string Page { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public bool Blank { get; set; }
            public int Level { get; set; }
            public int? mainNavOrder { get; set; }
            public string[] sections { get; set; }
            public SitemapNode[] subNodes { get; set; }

            public static SitemapNode GetNode(XElement p3, int level)
            {
                return new SitemapNode
                {
                    Title = (string)p3.Attribute("title"),
                    Action = (string)p3.Attribute("action") ?? "Index",
                    Controller = (string)p3.Attribute("controller"),
                    Page = (string)p3.Attribute("page") ?? "",
                    Description = (string)p3.Attribute("description") ?? "",
                    Blank = bool.Parse((string)p3.Attribute("blank") ?? "false"),
                    Level = p3.Ancestors().Count(),
                    mainNavOrder = (int?)p3.Attribute("mainNavOrder") ?? 0,
                    sections = p3.Elements("alternativeSection")
                                .Select(n => (string)n.Attribute("name")).ToArray(),
                    subNodes = p3.Elements("level" + (level + 1).ToString()).Select(pn => GetNode(pn, level + 1)).ToArray()
                };

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you for taking the time to help me out. I appreciate it.

Comment: The why did I get a minus 2 score?  I modified the code to put the GetNode into the class SitemapNode.  Make sure you use the update.

Comment: I did not put the -1. In fact, I put +1 and marked it as the answer. But yes, thank you. I did put that method into the SitemapNode class. 
Thanks again.